# Vim: how to join inline linebreaks in free text fields?

Tags: vim, line-breaks

I have free text

```
"starthello","hello 
 helloInline
 helloInline2","hello2","new field"
"not this","no inline line breaks","no","no"
```

where I would like to join it with `"$^ "` to

```
"starthello","hello helloInline helloInline2","hello2","new field"
"not this","no inline line breaks","no","no"
```

**How can I join inline line breaks in Vim?**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
:g/[^"]$/.,/"/j
```

Here's how it works:

```
:g/                 # On every line matching this regex:
   [^"]$            #   A line that does *not* end with a double quote
        /           # Run this command:
         .,         #   On every line from the current line until
           /"/      #   The next line containing a double quote
                    #   Run this command:
              j     #     Join (remove newlines)
```

Comment: Shorter version: `:v/"$/,//j`

Comment: @PeterRincker That's not quite right because I don't think it needs to go to a line ending in `"`, just a line containing `"`. But `:v/"$/,/"/j` should work

Comment: `:v/"$/,/"/j` will fail if you have more than one field that is broken up by line-breaks for a given record. It will not properly join the entire record onto one line. Assuming that a record ends with `"` which I believe is a safe assumption, then using it with the `:j` range will do just fine.

Comment: What is the construction `.,/"` called? Why is / needed, to escape or special character to denote some special mode? So this is the same as `:g@[^"]$@.,/"@j`?

Answer (score 1):

There might be other ways to do this, but one way would be to visually select the lines you want to join by pressing `Shift+V` and moving cursor up or down. Then pressing `Shift + J` to join the selected lines.